# @State var with array does not update view when grandchild updates it

Tags: swiftui

I have 3 views. The issue I have is that the 1st one (a parent view of 2) is not changing when the 3rd one (a children of view 2) has updated a property in the array.
Let's use some code so it is easier to understand:

```
public struct Item {
    public let id: String
    public var name: String?
    public var inStock: Bool
```

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ThisIsMessedUpApp: App {
var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ItemsMainView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ItemsMainView: View {
    @State var items = [Item]()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Item count is \(items.count)")
            Divider()
            VStack {
                Text("ItemsMainView has:")
                HStack {
                    ForEach(self.items, id: \.id) { item in
                        Text(item.name ?? "nothing found")
                        Spacer()
                        Text(item.inStock.description)
                    }
                }
            }
            ItemsView(items: $items)

        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ItemsView: View {
    @Binding var items: [Item]
    var body: some View {
        Button("Add new item (call made from ItemsView", action: {
            self.items.append(Item(id: UUID().uuidString,
                                   name: "Test #1",
                                   inStock: false))
        })
        VStack {
            ForEach($items, id: \.id) { $item in
                ItemView(item: $item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ItemView: View {
    @Binding var item: Item

    @State var draftItemName: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        Text("ItemView has")
        HStack {
            TextField("TextField", text: $draftItemName)
                .onSubmit {
                    item.name = draftItemName
                }
            Spacer()
            Text(item.inStock.description)
        }
        .onAppear {
            draftItemName = item.name ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

Some of the `Text` are for debugging purposes.
If you run this code and change the second `TextField`'s value to, say, "Test #2", you will see that you end up with an inconsistent UI state: `ItemsMainView` has "Test #1", whereas `ItemView` has "Test #2"

Comment: in your `ItemsMainView`, use `ForEach($items, id: \.id) { $item in...}`

Comment: I don't see why that would fix it. Can you explain? I am not changing anything in the ForEach. Also, `items` has property wrapper @State, and when `[Items]` changes, the view hierarchy that depends on it changes too.

Comment: The problem must be in how the 3rd view's `item` (ItemView) binds. It does not seem to.

Comment: I am starting to suspect this has to do with the 3rd view binding to an already bound variable. Normally, one binds a variable to a state variable from a parent view but I am sort of adding another view to the mix.

Comment: upon further tests, your original code works for me now! ios 16 and MacCatalyst, and on macos only.

Comment: when you say it works, you mean you don't see an inconsistent UI state?

Comment: that's right. I click/tap on the button, I get a new item with "Test #1", change the text to "xxxxxxxx", and press return. Then this is reflected in the `ItemsMainView`.

Comment: That is strange. I dont see that behavior. 
Anybody else can confirm? Ty!!!

Comment: note, for convenience/preference, I put the `HStack {...}` inside the `ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in ..}` and add `.foregroundColor(.red)` to the `Text`.
 I'm on MacOS 13.2, Xcode 14.2, tested on real ios 16.3 devices, macCatalyst and macos 13.2 only.

Comment: I can confirm. I copy/pasted your code, added a missing closing brace on the struct. Tested with an iPhone11 device (iOS16) using latest Xcode. Click on button, get a new item with "Test #1", change that text to "Test #2", and press return. Tested with multiple button clicks and various edits. Text values remained consistent between both views.

Comment: huh....mine does not update the 1st Test #1.

Comment: One last thought: If I press the tab button or the dismiss keyboard button when running your code on an iPad, then the text that shows in the textField doesn't update on the parent. In your code, entered text will only update when pressing the return key (i.e., submit code). I ran into that problem awhile back on some dev code and had to add focusState to also respond to tab or dismiss keyboard buttons.

Comment: the thing is I have a print out in .onSubmit which gets called! So, the assignment item.name = draftItemName is definitely hit. Not sure what is going on on my side :(

Comment: I pasted your code into a Swift Playground on my iPad running iPadOS 16.3 beta and it works correctly. Note that the simulator, and Xcode previews (which run in the simulator), are notorious for having bugs that don't exist on real devices.

Comment: I posted in the accepted answer the reason my actual code wasn't working. thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode 14.2, create a new project for ios or macos. Copy and paste the following code, replacing
the original `ContentView`.

Tell us if this code, tested on real ios 16.3 devices (not Previews), macCatalyst and MacOS 13.2 only, works for you.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ItemsMainView()
    }
}

public struct Item {
    public let id: String
    public var name: String?
    public var inStock: Bool
}

struct ItemsMainView: View {
    @State var items = [Item]()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Item count is \(items.count)")
            Divider()
            VStack {
                Text("ItemsMainView has:")
                ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                    HStack {
                        Text(item.name ?? "nothing found").foregroundColor(.red)
                        Spacer()
                        Text(item.inStock.description).foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                }
            }
            ItemsView(items: $items)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemsView: View {
    @Binding var items: [Item]
    var body: some View {
        Button("Add new item (call made from ItemsView", action: {
            self.items.append(Item(id: UUID().uuidString, name: "Test #1", inStock: false))
        }).buttonStyle(.bordered)
        VStack {
            ForEach($items, id: \.id) { $item in
                ItemView(item: $item)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    @Binding var item: Item
    @State var draftItemName: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("ItemView has")
        HStack {
            TextField("TextField", text: $draftItemName)
                .onSubmit {
                    item.name = draftItemName
                }
            Spacer()
            Text(item.inStock.description)
        }
        .onAppear {
            draftItemName = item.name ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it does work. 
What a strange thing that it does not work in my other project, where I wrote this code alongside existing code to test some concepts.

Comment: found why!!!

add this to the code 
extension Item: Identifiable, Equatable  {
    public static func == (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

that will make it not update the parent view.